# Convention on size of graph/network

Tags: graphical-model, graph-theory

Is there a standard that can help me define a network/graph as large or small?
I am testing a method and would need to see how my proposal works for large and small networks. It would help if there is an accepted guideline I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about social networks, then there is no such convention that works across disciplines.

Social network analysis has been used in all sorts of fields, some of which typically yield very small networks (e.g. intermarriages among the Medici and other families in Florence), some moderate sized (e.g. needle sharing among injection drug users) and some quite large (lots of things in physics).